# How to print line numbers for an event in Splunk

Tags: splunk-query

I wanted to print number of lines for an event in Splunk after querying it

Ex: `index=* host=* source=*application*` this query is giving all the events but I want to print/get number of lines for each and every event. I tried with `len()` of Splunk query but it didnt work for me

Comment: I believe `linecount` is the field you are looking for. It is one of the default fields that Splunk calculates for events.

Answer (score 0):

Actually every event contains 1 line only.

Even though size of the event is large but it is 1 json response only, so its treating complete response as 1 line response.

we can query based on characters

```
index=index-source host=hs* source=*appname* "TXNEnd" "SUCCESS" NOT "truncated" |where len(_raw) > 3000 |stats count by methodPath
```